# Função iloc[] em Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Vi um código que a função iloc estava assim:

```
x = dados.iloc[0:-1, d:]
y = dados.iloc[d].values[0]
```

Li que `iloc` Seleciona a linha e coluna, mas o que seria aquele `d` ali ?

Answer (score 2):

Adaptdado da [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

**DataFrame.iloc**
Indexação puramente baseada em localização através de inteiros para seleção por posição.

`iloc[]` é basicamente baseado em posções representadas por inteiros (de 0 ao tamanhyo-1 do eixo) mas também pode ser usado com um array booleano.

Entradas permitidas:

- Um inteiro, por exemplo 5
- Uma lista ou array de inteiros, ex. [4, 3, 0]
- Um um objeto do tipo `slice` de inteiros, ex. 1:7
- Um array booleano

Uma função que pode ser chamada com um argumento (Series, DataFrame ou Panel) e retorna uma saída válida para indexação (uma das opções acima). Isso é útil em cadeias de métodos, quando vc não tem uma referencia ao objeto de chamada, mas gostaria de basear sua seleção em algum valor. `.iloc` levantará a exceção `IndexError` se o índice requisitado estiver fora dos limites, embora a chmada via slices (de acordo com a semantica pyhton/numpy) admitam valores fora do limite.

**Exemplos:**

```
>>> mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
...           {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
...           {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
>>> df
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

Acessando a primeira linha do `df` com `iloc[0]`:

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64

# Investigando o tipo de objeto retornado qdo fazemos a chamada acima:
>>> type(df.iloc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Note que a chamada com `iloc[escalar]` não retorna um `Dataframe` e sim um objeto do tipo `pandas.series`.

Agora vamos acessar as duas primeiras linhas através de uma lista de inteiros:

```
>>>> df.iloc[[0, 1]]
     a    b    c    d
0    1    2    3    4
1  100  200  300  400

# Investigando o tipo de objeto retornado pela chamada acima:
>>> type(df.iloc[[0, 1]])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Veja que agora tipo de objeto do retorno foi um `pandas.DataFrame`, algo como um "subdataframe".

Acessando com slices:

```
# Extrapoloando o limite
>>> df.iloc[:60]
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000

# Começando em 2, indo até o final
>>> df.iloc[2::]
      a     b     c     d
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

Através de uma função, util em cadeia de metodos, no exemplo abaixo o indice é passado para lambda que retorna, ao fim, uma lista de inteiros pares.

```
>>> df.iloc[lambda x: x.index % 2 == 0]
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

Note que o retorno foi um `df` com as linhas cujos indices eram pares no `df` original.

**indexando os 2 eixos:**

Podemos, também, fazer um mix entre índices e colunas, no exemplo abaixo vamos acessar o valor da segunda coluna da primeira linha e depois os valores da primeira linha e terceira coluna mais a segunda linha e quarta coluna

```
# Acessando o valor da primeira linha nas segunda coluna
>>> df.iloc[0, 1]
2

# Acessando os valores presentes na primeira e segunda linha na terceira e quarta coluna, respectivamente.
df.iloc[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
      b     d
0     2     4
2  2000  4000
```

**Respondendo específicamente ao código na pergunta:**

Para elucidar o código colocado na pergunta, vamos definir um valor para a variável `d`, provavelmente esse codigo foi tirado de um contexto em que essa variável estava definida.

`x = dados.iloc[0:-1, d:]:`

```
# Vamos copiar o valor de `df` definido acima para um novo df chamado `dados
>>> dados = df.copy()

# Vamos definir a variável d com o valor 2
d = 2

# Executando o primeiro comando do codigo da pergunga
x = dados.iloc[0:-1, d:]

# Apresentando o resultado
print(x)
     c    d
0    3    4
1  300  400
```

O resultado é a terceira e a quarta colunas (`c` e `d`) das linhas `0` e `1`, note que o comando faz o que foi definido no tópico **Indexando os 2 eixos** com a utilização de slices, na semantica python/numpy, `dados.iloc[0:-1, d:]` indica um slice iniciando no índice 0 (linha 0) até a penúltimo ídicce (-1). As colunas foram selecionadas em função do valor da variável `d` (`=2`), ou seja da coluna 2 até a ultima (da `c` à `d`).

`y = dados.iloc[d].values[0]:`

Essa linha atribui à variável `y` o primeiro valor da terceira linha (visto que o valor da variável `d` é `2`) do dataframe, ou seja, `1000`:

```
# Relembrando os valores no dataframe
>>> print(dados)
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000

# Lista dos valores na linha do índice equivalente à variável `d`:
>>> dados.iloc[d].values
array([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])

# Executando segunda linha de codigo da pergunta
>>> y = dados.iloc[d].values[0]

# Apresentando o resultado:
print(y)
1000
```

Answer (score -1):

Não cheguei a usar pandas, então não cheguei a usar este método, pelo que li, o **`iloc`**, é um método de seleção de dados, e de acordo com [esse site](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/), sua estrutura funciona da seguinte forma:

```
data.iloc[<row selection>, <column selection>]
```

Então neste caso creio eu que está recuperando os valores da primeira linha até a última, na coluna d em diante.

```py
dados.iloc[0:-1, d:]  # a opção 0 é a primeira linha, é o -1 é a última, é o d: a partir da coluna d.
```

Claro não uso ciência de dados com python, mas pelo que ué li, creio que seja isso. Mas se alguém sabe é não for isso que disse posta aqui.